# How to find all TYPO3 TypoScript conditions which need traverse

Tags: typo3, typoscript

How can I find all affected TypoScript condition or is there a tool for doing this?

Is there a REGEX for finding all possibly affected TypoScript conditions such as:

```
mariadb> select uid,pid from sys_template where (config REGEXP '\\[ *request.getQueryParams()' or config REGEXP '\\[page\\[') and not hidden and not deleted;
...
```

---

**Background information:**

Since TYPO3 9.4, the TypoScript conditions are based on the Symfony expression language.

There is a problem with conditions (and other parts of TYPO3 which use the Symfony expression language, such as EXT:form) if they access uninitialized variables or not existing array elements. This is due to currently used Symfony expression language and AFAIK will be fixed in newer versions (of Symfony expression language).

Due to this problem, it is recommended to check for the not initialized variables / array elements and the recommended way is using "[traverse](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#condition-function-traverse)":

> page is only available in the frontend context. As the TypoScript setup may be loaded in some backend modules or the CLI context, it is considered best practice to always guard the property by using the function traverse()

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#page

**Examples:**

Change the conditions:

```
# before
-[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'] && request.getQueryParams() ['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0]
# after
+[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0]
```

---

```
# before
- [page["uid"] == 2]
# after
+ [traverse(page, "uid") == 2]
```

**Log**

If the problem occurs a log message is logged (this is with PHP 8.1 and TYPO3 v11):

```
PHP Warning: Undefined array key "uid" in /app/vendor/symfony/expression-language/Node/GetAttrNode.php line 97
```

**Resources**

- TYPO3 issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/95781

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64041806/typoscript-conditions-with-symfony-expression-language-throws-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since no answer so far ...

##### Solution 1 (long term):

Support effort for improving condition error detection and converting, e.g. by supporting SGalinski TypoScript plugin for PhpStorm (I am not affiliated with this in any way!):

- see issues: https://gitlab.sgalinski.de/phpstorm/phpstorm-typoscript-plugin/-/issues/?search=condition&sort=created_date&state=opened&first_page_size=20
- buy license https://www.sgalinski.de/en/typo3-products-web-development/typoscript-phpstorm-webstorm-intellij/

##### Solution 2

This is a very rough quick hack to sift through error logs, you may have to adapt this. This will only find errors in loaded TypoScript.

Apply this to the logs in var/log (Composer) or public/typo3temp/var/log (non Composer):

Check TypoScript ConditionMatching matches:

```
grep -a -E "TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.Configuration.TypoScript.ConditionMatching.ConditionMatcher" typo3_*.log
```

Show messages (unique) with: error message,code

```
grep -a -E "TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.Configuration.TypoScript.ConditionMatching.ConditionMatcher\": PHP Warning:(.*) in /var/www/site-uol11/vendor/symfony/expression-language/Node/GetAttrNode.php line 97- .* - \{\"expression\":([^:]*)\",\"exception\":\"TYPO3.*" typo3-error.log | perl -p -E "s/.*TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.Configuration.TypoScript.ConditionMatching.ConditionMatcher\": PHP Warning: (.*) in \/var\/www\/site-uol11\/vendor\/symfony\/expression-language\/Node\/GetAttrNode.php line 97- .* - \{\"expression\":([^:]*)\",\"exception\":\"TYPO3.*/\1,\2/" | sort -u
```

Output might be something like:

```
Undefined array key "uid","page[\"uid\"] == 17
```

You can then do a search for it (page["uid"]) in your TypoScript and change as outlined below

##### Solution 3

Search through your DB or TypoScript files using regular expression.

The following examples are incomplete, extend this with search for other problematic statements as mentioned in the question.

files:

```
find Configuration/TypoScript -type f -name "*.typoscript" | while read i;do grep -a -E "(^\[ *page\[)" "$i";if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo " in $i";fi;done
```

Example output:

```
[page["uid"] == 17]
 in Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript
```

Search in DB:

```
select uid,pid from sys_template where config REGEXP '... add regex here' and not deleted;
```

##### Change conditions

```
# before  
- [page["uid"] == 17]

# after
+ [traverse(page, "uid") == 17]
```

Official TYPO3 Documentation: [Using page in TypoScript Conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#page)

```
# before
-[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1'] && request.getQueryParams() ['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0]

# after
+[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi1/news') > 0]
```

Official TYPO3 Documentation: [Using request.getQueryParams in TypoScriptCondition](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#request-getqueryparams)